# How do I import data from a mysql 5.7 docker container into a mysql 8.0 docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker

Currently my database is stored on a Mysql 5.7 docker container, now I have created a new Mysql 8.0 container, I want to export the contents of the database in the Mysql 5.7 docker container and import it into the Mysql 8.0 container, I will use the Mysql 8.0 container in the future, how should I do this? What are the exact steps to do this?

Comment: Backup and restore.

Comment: dump the db from 5.7 and then import to the 8.0

Comment: @TruongDang，Is it a backup of every database in 5.7? Including the four databases information_schema, mysql, performance_schema, sys? Is it true that when importing, these four databases are also imported into 8.0?

Comment: No dont import any database across versions of MySQL that YOU didnt create yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.use some tools,for example Navicat

2.use mysql backup ways dump，and you can skip information_schema, mysql, performance_schema, sys.